# GUI not updating values in simple game

Tags: java, swing

I am making a simple 2d platforming game using Swing library, where I am trying to constantly show different values in the GUI. The values update and work perfectly in the first level, however they remain the same for the next levels.

Code for the GUI:

```
public class MyView extends UserView {

    Player player;

    private Image background;
    private Image newBackground;

    public MyView(World world, Player player, int width, int height) {
        super(world, width, height);
        this.player = player;
        this.background = new ImageIcon("data/rainy.gif").getImage()
                .getScaledInstance(1000, 1000, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintForeground(Graphics2D g) {
        g.drawString("Lives left: " + player.getLifeCount(), 650, 20);
        g.drawString("Blue hearts picked: " + player.getBlueHeartCount(), 650, 30);
        g.drawString("Time left: " + player.getTimeCounter(), 650, 50);
     }
    }
```

When reaching the second level, `player.getLifeCount()`, `player.getBlueHeartCount()` and `player.getTimeCounter()`, freeze and stop updating.

Here is the relevant code (without imports) for level 1 and level 2 where the values are changed:

```
public class Level1 extends GameLevel implements ActionListener {

@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (getPlayer().heartPick) {
            timer.stop();
        } else if (player.getTimeCounter() <= 0) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            counter -= 1;
            player.setTimeCounter(counter);
        }
    }
```

Code for level 2:

```
public class Level2 extends GameLevel implements ActionListener {

@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//        System.out.println("Action event!");
        if (getPlayer().heartPick) {
            timer.stop();
        } else if (player.getTimeCounter() <= 0) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            counter -= 1;
            player.setTimeCounter(counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant code for the main class:

```
public class Game {
    private GameLevel world;

    private MyView view;

    private int level;

    // timer
    private Timer timer;

    public Game(){

        // make the world
        level = 1;
        world = new Level1();
        world.populate(this);

        // make a view
        view = new MyView(world, world.getPlayer(), 800, 600);

        // display the view in a frame
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Event handling");

        // start!
        world.start();
    }

    // return world
    public GameLevel getWorld() {
            return world;
    }

    // the player in current level
    public Player getPlayer() {
        return world.getPlayer();
    }

    // Progress to next level
    public void goNextLevel() {
        world.stop();

        switch (level) {
            case 4:
                System.exit(0);
            case 2:
                level++;

                // get a new world
                world = new Level2();

                // fill world
                world.populate(this);

                // show the new world in the view
                view.setWorld(world);

                view.setBackground(2);
                world.start();
                break;

            case 3:
                level++;

                //get new world
                world = new Level3();

                //fill world
                world.populate(this);

                // show the new world in the view
                view.setWorld(world);

                view.setBackground(3);
                world.start();
                break;

            default:
                level++;
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try to simplify your code and focus on the issue itself. It is hard to go over all this code and trying to find the problem. Preparing a such simplified example may also help you finding the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I made some changes to keep the code as consise as posible, it's my first time writting a question in Stackoverflow. So thank you for letting me know. Hope it is better now

Comment: Your code makes heavy use of libraries that we have no access to, which will greatly hamper our ability to test it and understand where the bug might be coming from. You may be fully on your own for this one, but regardless, as @ehh suggests, simplify your own code until you can isolate the core that is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definitely try this method next time I run into a problem. (I'm sure it won't be too long before then).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `switch` statement in `goNextLevel` is switching based on the level you are GOING to be on instead of the level you are currently on. So when you are on Level 1 and hit the `goNextLevel` block, it goes to `default`. You want to switch based on what the level used to be, not what it will be, because you are updating it in that statement.

Comment: Sharp eyes. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful.